# javascript works in sandbox but not in browser

Tags: javascript, html, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I put together this code to produce a map centered on a location and tested it with multiple sandbox applications and it works, but when I try to run it from a .html file on my desktop the page is blank. Does anyone have any ideas on what i'm doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user- scalable=no">
  <title>OKC MapView - Create a 2D map - 4.1</title>
  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #viewDiv {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.1/esri/css/main.css">
  <script <!-- src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.1/"> //--></script>

  <script>
  <!--
    require([ 
      "esri/Map",
      "esri/views/MapView",
      "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(Map, MapView) {

      var map = new Map({ 
        basemap: "togo"
      });

      var view = new MapView({
        container: "viewDiv",
        map: map, 
        zoom: 10, 
        center: [-97.508, 35.482] 
      });

    });
    //-->
  </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <div id="viewDiv"></div> 
  </body>                    
  </html>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the Console in the developer tools? What error messages are displayed?

Comment: I didn't see any errors but I did use an online development tool instead of something more robust

Comment: "I was trying to open it directly as a file:///" … "an online development tool" — These statements appear contradictory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to open the file directly as `file:///` then it might not work, as you need to host it in a website.

There is no service by name "togo" it needs to be "topo".

Also, get rid of the un-necessary comments `<!-- -->`

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: I was trying to open it directly as a file:///, so that explains it! I am new to javascript so thank you so much for your advice!